Two separate session/user/{something}
I have Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in my local machine. I want to have two separate {something} to solve my problem.
I am using my Ubuntu for all my works; I have a side project/hustle and my requirement is to keep them completely unaware of each other. That means, separate files, separate apps(Chrome, Slack, VS Code, docker ps should also not show the images of other {something}). Also when I am in one {something}, I shouldn't mistakenly edit/change/visualize things in other.
Consider it as I want to work on something on night/weekends and switch back to my main work in day time. Smooth transition and privacy is the main concern.

Two different users, one of which has sudo privileges, should do.

will i be able to use 2 applications(slack, chrome,etc)

If absolute isolation is a requirement, VMs are a good way to keep things distinct. If this is being done on a work-supplied machine, though, there may be policies in place to report system usage

If this is hardware that you own, then just create an additional user account. This is precisely what user accounts are for. Applications, if installed properly, should keep data 100% separate. Linux has been a multi-user system for decades.
If this is somebody else's hardware (like a work-issued laptop), then DON'T. Use their hardware for the intended purpose only. Misuse may be a reason to fire you.

was a bit skeptical about two users, but worked like a charm.
